# Failed to resolve assembly

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

I'm new to xamari. I'm trying to run my project but i keep getting this error:

[image]

[image]

the issue started after adding a new content page to the project, i can't find out what's the issue, the content page has the assembly name on it, look:

[image]

i'm trying to follow this tutorial:
[Xamarin.Forms Multiscreen Quickstart](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/getting-started/hello-xamarin-forms-multiscreen/quickstart/)

what should i do? 
[windows 10, Visual Studio 2017 community]

Comment: Hard to tell w/o source. But, it looks like you did not download the source for the example. In that example, in the codebehind in App.xaml.cs is Phoneword.

Comment: Download the whole sample project and analyse. If you are new to C#, don't waste your time.