# Xamarin project not running, assembly not found

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Im learning Xamarin,  when I try to create a project and build it, it gives me this error:

> The "Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.GetTasksAbi" task could not be loaded
>   from the assembly ,
>   C:\Users\XXXX.nuget\packages\xamarin.forms\3.0.0.482510\build\netstandard2.0\Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.dll.
>   Could not load file or assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral

I really dont know how to solve it. I installed Visual Studio with Xamarin found at this  [link](https://www.visualstudio.com/es/xamarin/)

Comment: So you are creating a new clean Xamarin.Forms project and try to build it right away without any modifications?

Comment: same issue here :( please somebody help us

Comment: my case https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48255687/failed-to-resolve-assembly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all the suggestions. I just updated Windows 10 and it worked. I had and old Windows build so I guess it was  related to my Windows being  outdated.

Comment: yes, .net standard 2.0 requires Build 16299 (Windows 10 v1709 - Fall Creators Update). so you used an older version like 1703 or 1607.

Comment: yes... upgrading windows 10 to version 1803 worked for me as well

Answer (score 2):

This is the cause:

> Could not load file or assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral

Starting with Xamarin-Forms 3, XF has moved to [.Net Standard 2.0](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/pull/1306), so you need to [create a library against .net standard 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/library-with-visual-studio).

[image]

Comment: I did that but the error still occurs. Basically I did this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/internals/net-standard  but it doesnt work, the same error pops up when building the solution

Comment: When adding Xamarin.Forms to the library dependencies, it shows as yellow triangles, but if I use Xamarin.Forms 2.4 it doesn-t

Comment: have you created a .net standard 2.0 lib? is the net standard 2.0.3 package installed?