# The "Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.GetTasksAbi" task could not be loaded from the assembly

Tags: xamarin.forms

I was enjoying with Microsoft Visual studio 2017(Community version) latest version of xamarin forms. but randomly i got this error.
Project Details:
Xamarin forms using .NET Standard library. I have lot of effort to resolve it. even i have reinstall  visual studio 3 times. but there is no success.

[image: Error Details]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xamarin project not running, assembly not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50372727/xamarin-project-not-running-assembly-not-found)

Comment: this was [already asked/answered](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50372727/1466046). update your Windows 10 to at least 1709

Answer (score 1):

I had this Problem in past and After trying every thing the below solution worked for me

A solution library required the Microsoft.Bcl.Build package in the project that reference in your solution installed the package via nuget and it would start working

Hope it Works

Comment: I have tried as you mentioned. But still issue appearing. Can you please let me know the steps: "A solution library required the Microsoft.Bcl.Build package in the project that reference in your solution installed the package via nuget and it would start working"

Comment: run this in your package manager cli   -   Install-Package Microsoft.Bcl.Build -Version 1.0.21

Answer (score 0):

I've also run into this error. Check that all your projects are targeting the same version of xamarin.

Comment: I have already checked same things and all targeting version of xamarin forms same . Can you please provide other solution

Answer (score 0):

There are a few steps to fix that error:

1 - Check Xamarin.Forms version in all projects, it should be
    exactly the same.

2 - Clean Solution

3 - Restart Visual Studio

4 - If it doesn't work, go to the Folder and delete Bin and Obj folders.

Everytime I face a issue like that, usually these steps are more than enough.

As a last resort, you can Load and Unload the Projects in the Solution.

Comment: I have already checked same things and all targeting version of xamarin forms same . Can you please provide other solution