# "Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.GetTasksAbi" task could not be loaded from the assembly

Tags: .net, xamarin.forms

Already found same problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51167243/the-xamarin-forms-build-tasks-gettasksabi-task-could-not-be-loaded-from-the-as), but that not solve my problem.

Exception details:

> Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error The "Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.GetTasksAbi" task could not be loaded from the assembly C:\Users\sonub.nuget\packages\xamarin.forms\2.5.1.527436\build\netstandard1.0\Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.dll. Confirm that the declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.

I have installed xamarin forms 3.1.0.912540 from 2.5.0.121934 for all the platforms. After that, I got this error. I research about this error and someone said that install .NET Framework 4.7.1 would help solve this issue.

**But after installing .Net Framework getting the same error. Installer screenshot after installing .Net Framework.**
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xamarin project not running, assembly not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50372727/xamarin-project-not-running-assembly-not-found)

Comment: update your Windows 10 build to 1803/1809

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally this error will indeed come from the fact that .Net framework is missing.
Check the download section here depending on the OS you are on

https://www.microsoft.com/net/download?initial-os=windows

For reference, details about the actual problem can be found here https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/2690#issuecomment-388727429

Comment: Also getting following error: Unhandled Exception: Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParseException: <Timeout exceeded getting exception details>

Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParseException: Position 346:57. Can not find the object referenced by `DashBoardPage`
This error is also come after updating xamarin forms

Comment: XamlParseException often just points to wrong Xaml in your page... without any code hard to tell

Comment: After instaling .Net framework same error showing in the windwos part, I added the screenshot with the question.