# A freshly created Xamarin.Forms project does not build

Tags: xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017, .net-standard-2.0

I am trying to create a Xamarin.Forms application in Visual Studio 2017, version 15.7.6, on a 64-bit Windows 7. Whichever code sharing strategy I choose, the application does not build as expected and shows the following error message: "Could not load file or assembly netstandard version 2.0". However, when I create a .NET standard library and a console application that uses it, it works fine. ASP.NET Core Web project creation also works.

What could be wrong with .NET Standard on my machine?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xamarin project not running, assembly not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50372727/xamarin-project-not-running-assembly-not-found)

Comment: update your Windows 10 to v1803

Comment: @magicandre1981 I am on Windows 7. Am I out of luck?

Comment: Android / iOS should work, but not UWP, so delete the UWP project

Comment: @magicandre1981 UWP is not even an option for me as I run Windows 7. It's already absent.

Comment: do the upgrade to Windows 10 (this is still free, I just done this 1 week ago and Win10 was activated from Win7 device)