# The "Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.GetTasksAbi" task could not be loaded from the assembly Confirm that the <UsingTask> declaration is correct

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

After creating a xamarin cross-platform project I tried to run the project but I come up with the folloing errors and warnings. I tried many solutions from this website but I could not solve the problem.

here are the errors and warnings: [any help]

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Warning     The 'packages' element is not declared. App4.Droid  C:\Users\Dhafer\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\App4\App4\App4.Droid\packages.config  2
>   Warning     An unexpected error occurred trying to initialize Android Designer. Please verify the Android SDK path and the  Java Development Kit path on Tools->Options->Xamarin->Android Settings menu. Please see the logs for more details.          0
>   Warning     The 'packages' element is not declared. App4    C:\Users\Dhafer\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\App4\App4\App4\packages.config    2
>   Error       The "Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.GetTasksAbi" task could not be loaded from the assembly C:\Users\Dhafer\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\App4\packages\Xamarin.Forms.3.1.0.697729\build\netstandard1.0\Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.dll. Could not load file or assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. Confirm that the  declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask. App4
>   Error       The "Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.GetTasksAbi" task could not be loaded from the assembly C:\Users\Dhafer\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\App4\packages\Xamarin.Forms.3.1.0.697729\build\netstandard1.0\Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.dll. Could not load file or assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. Confirm that the  declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask. App4.Droid
>   Error       The "Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.GetTasksAbi" task could not be loaded from the assembly C:\Users\Dhafer\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\App4\packages\Xamarin.Forms.3.1.0.697729\build\netstandard1.0\Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.dll. Could not load file or assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. Confirm that the  declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask. App4.iOS
>   Warning     The referenced component 'Xamarin.Forms.Platform' could not be found.   App4
>   Warning     The referenced component 'Xamarin.Forms.Xaml' could not be found.   App4
>   Warning     The referenced component 'Xamarin.Forms.Core' could not be found.   App4
>   Warning IDE0006 Error encountered while loading the project. Some project features, such as full solution analysis for the failed project and projects that depend on it, have been disabled.   App4        1   Active
>   Warning     The referenced component 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat' could not be found. App4.Droid
>   Warning     The referenced component 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView' could not be found.  App4.Droid
>   Warning     The referenced component 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter' could not be found.   App4.Droid
>   Warning     The referenced component 'Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android' could not be found.   App4.Droid
>   Warning     The referenced component 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v4' could not be found.   App4.Droid
>   Warning     The referenced component 'System.ObjectModel' could not be found.   App4.Droid
>   Warning     The referenced component 'Mono.Android' could not be found. App4.Droid
>   Warning     The referenced component 'System.Xml.Linq' could not be found.  App4.Droid
>   Warning     The referenced component 'System' could not be found.   App4.Droid
>   Warning     The referenced component 'System.Core' could not be found.  App4.Droid
>   Warning     The referenced component 'Xamarin.Forms.Xaml' could not be found.   App4.Droid
>   Warning     The referenced component 'mscorlib' could not be found. App4.Droid
>   Warning     The referenced component 'Xamarin.Forms.Core' could not be found.   App4.Droid
>   Warning     The referenced component 'FormsViewGroup' could not be found.   App4.Droid
>   Warning     The referenced component 'System.Xml' could not be found.   App4.Droid
>   Warning     The referenced component 'Xamarin.Forms.Platform' could not be found.   App4.Droid
>   Warning     The referenced component 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Design' could not be found.   App4.Droid
>   Warning IDE0006 Error encountered while loading the project. Some project features, such as full solution analysis for the failed project and projects that depend on it, have been disabled.   App4.Droid      1   Active
>   Warning     The referenced component 'System.Core' could not be found.  App4.iOS
>   Warning     The referenced component 'Xamarin.Forms.Xaml' could not be found.   App4.iOS
>   Warning     The referenced component 'Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS' could not be found.   App4.iOS
>   Warning     The referenced component 'Xamarin.Forms.Platform' could not be found.   App4.iOS
>   Warning     The referenced component 'System' could not be found.   App4.iOS
>   Warning     The referenced component 'System.Xml' could not be found.   App4.iOS
>   Warning     The referenced component 'Xamarin.iOS' could not be found.  App4.iOS
>   Warning     The referenced component 'Xamarin.Forms.Core' could not be found.   App4.iOS
>   Warning IDE0006 Error encountered while loading the project. Some project features, such as full solution analysis for the failed project and projects that depend on it, have been disabled.   App4.iOS        1   Active

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xamarin project not running, assembly not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50372727/xamarin-project-not-running-assembly-not-found)

Comment: do some searching before posting. This question gets asked daily. With XF 3 code was moved to .net standard 2.0 and so you need Win10 1709/1803. Also you need VS2017, not VS2015 (C:\Users\Dhafer\Documents\Visual Studio **2015** \Projects)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xamrain form build task reference error in visual studio 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51821450/xamrain-form-build-task-reference-error-in-visual-studio-2017)