# Xamarin.Forms.3.0 Error Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.GetTasksAbi

Tags: android, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

i am using visual studio 2017 , i have install xamrain form Xamarin.Forms.3.0.0.561731 and remove previous version then install this version then when i run project then i get the this error. Any expert can tell me where i am wrong and what is the problem .

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error     The "Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.GetTasksAbi" task could not be
>   loaded from the assembly
>   D:\Practics\xamrain\SQLite\packages\Xamarin.Forms.3.0.0.561731\build\netstandard2.0\Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.dll.
>   Could not load file or assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. Confirm that
>   the  declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its
>   dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class
>   that implements
>   Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.  SQLite.Android  D:\Practics\xamrain\SQLite\packages\Xamarin.Forms.3.0.0.561731\build\netstandard2.0\Xamarin.Forms.targets   36
>
> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error     The "Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.GetTasksAbi" task could not be
>   loaded from the assembly
>   D:\Practics\xamrain\SQLite\packages\Xamarin.Forms.3.0.0.561731\build\netstandard1.0\Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.dll.
>   Could not load file or assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. Confirm that
>   the  declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its
>   dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class
>   that implements
>   Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.  SQLite  D:\Practics\xamrain\SQLite\packages\Xamarin.Forms.3.0.0.561731\build\netstandard1.0\Xamarin.Forms.targets   36

Comment: Do you by chance have mismatched versions of `Xamarin.Forms` between your projects?

Comment: i removed previous xamrain form 2.4 then install xamrain form 3.0 and also dev express data grid then i run this project and i got this error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xamarin project not running, assembly not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50372727/xamarin-project-not-running-assembly-not-found)

Comment: update Windows 10 to at least 1709

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try these steps:

1. Unload project from the solution
2. Restart visual studio and open solution
3. Reload project
4. Rebuild

i find a similar discussion about this,you can refer to [this link](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/106784/error-with-latest-nuget-v2-5-0-77-xamarin-forms-build-tasks-gettasksabi-task-could-not-be-loaded).