# 'Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks, Version = 0.0.0.0 , Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken = null 'or one of its dependencies

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I picked up a code from last year.
I fill in the solution and I get the error in question.

> Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.dll Failed to load file or assembly
> 'Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks, Version = 0.0.0.0 , Culture = neutral,
> PublicKeyToken = null 'or one of its dependencies.

I tried all the solutions on the net by deleting the packages, the bin and obj, updating the version of `xamarin.forms` but nothing.
it doesn't work, can you help me.
Thank you
Marco

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does [this help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50372727/xamarin-project-not-running-assembly-not-found)?

Comment: Sounds like an old project. The .csproj file is likely using an older way to build. You might be better off creating a brand new empty Xamarin Forms solution and project. Targetting your platforms of interest. Then manually move the source files into that. Alternatively, after creating a brand new solution, open the `.csproj` files of the cross-platform project in it. (The project that contains `.xaml` files). Compare that `.csproj` file to the one in your code, side-by-side in a text editor. Something in there is a clue to how to fix the problem.